# How can I use an audio file without having to re-encode it to output an audio stream with the same format?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I have two input files, a still image that's going to repeat itself as frames and an audio file.

How can I use the audio file without having to re-encode it to output an audio stream with the same format as the audio file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest would be:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

This will encode the image with x264 to an H.264 video stream and leave the audio stream untouched (by using the `copy` encoder). The `-shortest` option makes ffmpeg stop when the shortest input ends, i.e. the audio file.

Note that the audio stream determines the output formats available to you. If you have a PCM audio file (i.e. a `.wav` of some sort), you cannot use MP4 containers. If you have MPEG-1 Layer III audio (MP3) or AAC audio (an `.m4a` for example), the MP4  container will work. Check the [Comparison of container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) to get an idea of what's possible.

See also: [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) and the [x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for tweaking the quality of the output.